# How to create iPhone "photofolder" like in Photos.app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Iam sure this is a dumb questions, but I've been searching all over the place without knowing what exactly Iam looking for. Is there a way to efficiently create a "photofolder" like the one in the standard Photos.app. Facebook seems to have this built in.
I guess I could have "hacked" a way to do it eventually, but Iam concerned with memory and best-practices. I've added an image to illustrate my what I want:
[image: iphone photo album]
<sub>(source: [bhs4.com](http://img.bhs4.com/47/a/47aa0cb17e97ccf20e32daec079ab938735d73c8_large.jpg))</sub>

So to be short; I want the thumbnail/folder look. Any good guides/tips?

Edit: Iam going to get images the images from Instagram if that matters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple appears to be using a **`UICollectionView`** to display the images in a 'thumbnail grid' fashion.

For more info, Google `UICollectionView`

Comment: Here is a good place to start with UICollectionView:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly what I was looking for! Did you knew it, or is there someplace to look up which components Apple uses in their own applications? By the way, thanks a lot for the tutorial! Seems like I only need to modify a few things to make it work with Instagram - plus, now I know what to Google!

Comment: @SteffenMartinsen Nope, didn't know. After a while, you can kind of tell what people are using in their app. There isn't really any way to *really* know what Apple does in their apps

Answer (score 1):

There are some open-source posibilities to display a photo-browse view controller. Search on github. I have found https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser, which seems to be exactly what you are looking for, but there are other similar alternatives as well.
Hope it helps!